# How do I make a subroutine that accepts an array *or* a variable number of scalars?

Tags: arrays, perl, scalar

I'm looking to make a subroutine `mysub` which should behave such that the following two calls are effectively the same.

```
mysub(["values", "in", "a", "list"]);
mysub("Passing", "scalar", "values");
```

What is the proper syntax to make this happen?

Comment: Perl's `system` function doesn't handle array reference arguments very well (unless you have a program called `ARRAY(0xa63af0)` in your path).

Comment: Hmmm... This is still what I want. I'm not sure what made be think this is how system works. Thanks, I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check if `@_` contains a single array reference.

```
sub mysub {
    if ( @_ == 1 && ref( $_[0] ) eq 'ARRAY' ) {
        # Single array ref
    } else {
        # A list
    }
}
```

The `if` clause checks that only one argument was passed and that the argument is an array reference using [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html). To make sure that the cases are the same:

```
sub mysub {
    if ( @_ == 1 && ref( $_[0] ) eq 'ARRAY' ) {
        @_ = @{ $_[0] };
    }
    # Rest of the code
}
```